# Can we use a spreadsheet as a front-end form instead of using html for a webapp?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm currently creating a system of data entry - data storage where users will fill-in data in their own spreadsheet form, and all of their data are collected into another spreadsheet. Connecting and collecting data from multiple sheets are difficult in terms of privacy and processing. I was thinking if it's possible to use a spreadsheet as a front-end for a webapp instead of using an html.

Comment: I think it'll be much hard though - in terms of privacy and processing.

Comment: @TheMaster I see. If we set aside the privacy, is this difficult in terms of sending data to storage sheet?

Comment: Should be possible with a installed edit trigger. But there are many issues - what about users who would  want to simultaneously fill up the form? Won't they see each other's answers(Note that spreadsheet syncs in the cloud)?  Are you going to provide  each user a separate sheet(If so, you should be the owner of all sheets)?

Comment: I guess what I'm thinking is not really possible.

Comment: Have you considered getting all of the data using the Sheets API and a language like Python or  Java.  There are probably a lot cloud resources that I don't know much about that could do something like that very quickly and securely.

Answer (score 1):

Using a spreadsheet as a front-end form instead of using HTML for a web app is technically possible, but it is not a recommended approach for several reasons.

Limited Functionality: Spreadsheets are primarily designed for data analysis and calculations, not for creating interactive user interfaces. They lack the flexibility and functionality that HTML and web technologies provide, such as dynamic content, responsive design, and interactivity.

User Experience: Spreadsheets are not intuitive for data entry and can be confusing for users who are not familiar with spreadsheet software. HTML forms, on the other hand, are specifically designed for data input and provide a more user-friendly experience.

Data Validation and Processing: HTML forms offer built-in validation and processing capabilities, allowing you to enforce data constraints and perform actions based on user input. Spreadsheets may not provide the same level of control and flexibility for data validation and processing.

Privacy and Security: Using spreadsheets for data entry can raise privacy and security concerns. Spreadsheets are typically stored locally or on cloud storage platforms, which may not have the same level of security measures as a web application. Additionally, sharing and managing access to spreadsheets can be more challenging compared to a web app with proper authentication and authorization mechanisms.

Instead of using a spreadsheet as a front-end form, it is recommended to leverage HTML and web technologies to create a user-friendly and secure web app. HTML forms can be easily customized and styled to match your desired design, and you can use JavaScript and server-side technologies to handle data processing, validation, and storage. This approach provides a more robust and scalable solution for your data entry and storage needs.

Comment: I understand. In terms of privacy, I just want to hide the script and the storage sheet from users. In terms of using html, I just prefer using the sheet since my team are familiar with it. If it's possible, is there any resource you can point me to get started?

Comment: If you wish to hide the script from the users then they will not be able to edit the form unless your willing to go to the  extra trouble of creating an addon.